# How to install Windows 7 a guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Trying to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox from Windows 7 DVD but won't install. Does it only install from a ISO file or something?

Comment: any errors? that might help narrow down the issue

Comment: If you do have a DVD you could use IMGBurn and create an ISO file and use that for Virtual Box

Answer (score 2):

What is the actual errors you are getting?

Virtual Box should act pretty much like a physical machine and there should be little to no difference.

It can mount either a physical disk or an ISO of Windows.

I would just double check the basics:

1. Make sure you have the minimum 1GB of memory .
2. [Make sure you meet the minimum requirements if trying to use the 64 bit edition of Windows](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)
3. Make sure that the virtual hard drive is at least 20GBs.

If none of these help, please state the actual problem you have.

Comment: Hi The install from the win 7 DVD starts the error is:VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot. Please ensure that you have enabled VT-x/AMD-V properly in the BIOS of your host computer. Havn't got a clue how to do that.

Comment: I will start by saying, if you download or have access to the 32 bit version of Windows, you will probably have a much simpler life! - Excluding this, the only thing you can do is go in to your BIOS (usually either press F2 or delete when your machine starts) and look around for an option such as VT/Virtualisation etc. and set it to enabled. If you don't see it, it is possible your BIOS does not support it.

Comment: Hi Thanks Bios change worked well. Much appreciated. Is there a way to stop the win 7 guest from connecting to the net so I don't have to keep updating the os to keep it secure when I'm just using the Vm to try out new programs?

Comment: @Tim - yep, go in to the settings of the virtual machine and simply disable or delete the network card.

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion of deleting/disabling network card. By doing this you can't access shared folders located in host machine. I would prefer going through Control panel - Austomatic Updates - Turn off Automatic Updates.